# onActivityResult for PlusOneButton

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-plus-one, android-googleapiclient

In Android, I am trying to use the g+1 in my App. On clicking the g+1 a pop up open with the button "OK", "Share" and "UNDO". I need to know what button user has pressed.

Is it possible to capture it ?

Comment: I wonder, why it is down voted. I am not concerned just because it is down voted. It would be wise if any explanation is give so that other will understand it and avoid it in future.

Comment: Please check the demo here: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin I tried and didn't see any `pop up` window.

Comment: Which example talks about plusone button